# Why is a differentiable manifold first countable?

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm reading Margalef's Differential topology p.42

Let $X$ be a differentiable (Banach) manifold. (We are only assuming that there is a differentiable atlas on $X$ and topology on $X$ is induced from the equivalence class of that atlas) Then, why is $X$ first countable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any locally metrizable space is first countable.  Given such a space $X$ and a point $x\in X$, let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x$ with a metric $d$.   Then if we let $B_n = \{u\in U, d(x,u) < 1/n\}$, the collection $\{B_n\}$ forms a countable local basis for the point $x$, as desired.

Note that being a manifold automatically implies local metrizability.